# How to distinguish NumberPoint and FieldSeparators with comma

Tags: import

[image]Hello,

I have a problem with importing .txt file which uses "," as decimal as well as field operator.
I need to convert numbers with decimal comma to decimal point and create field operator to separate them. I tried to use command FieldSeparators and NumberPoint but I think there is no chance Mathematica can understand and distinguish between Number and Field Sparators.

```
Section1 = Import["C:\\Desktop\\Section1.TXT",{"Data"},"FieldSeparators"->","];
TimeSection = Section1[[3;;Length[Section1],1]];
CurrentSection1 = NumberForm[Section1[[3;;Length[Section1],7]],NumberPoint->","]
```

And all I got is what you can see on the pic.
Any one knows how to fix this issue?

Thank you for your help.

I cannot change the format for decimal point before import since the txt is generated by electric quality-meter device and exported via speacial program and I have many of these txt files so If I changed it manually it would be very time-consuming.

Here is the link for my .txt: [https://pastebin.com/raw/udcFTuG7](https://pastebin.com/raw/udcFTuG7%22)

Update: I have figured out that actually the field separator is not in form "," but has extra space behind comma hence ", " so I wrote "FieldSeparators"->", " but I got the same result.

Comment: Is there any way for the original file to *not* use the comma as a field separator?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way or at least there is no way to do it automatically. These results are generated from electric quality-meter device and I can only open in a special software which can export data in this txt way and I cannot change the format. Device is designed for european market so it uses decimal commas. I could do it maybe manually in csv format or manually change comma for point using ctrl+h in notepad but since I have tons of these txt files it would be very time-consuming.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to confirm that your situation forces you to have commas pull double-duty (which is really unadvisable otherwise). I think you should include this extra information in your question.

Comment: I updated my question. Anyway, I think the solution could be that actually between every number there is as fieldseparator comma and space therefore it is ", " not just "," so it might be used for "FieldSeparators"->", " but it doesn't work or I may have used it wrongly.

Comment: To confirm, you already tried the experiment of using `"FieldSeparators" -> ", "`, and it led to the same result, or did you get a different error altogether?

Comment: Yes, the result was the same, but I still think it could be solution because the extra space behind the comma is the only difference between decimal comma and field separator in this case.

Comment: @Vocis in the file you linked the fields are NOT separated by commas, but instead by what appears to be tabs, or spaces perhaps. I think the commas you see are list delimiters in Mathematica, but they are not there in the original file. Try to import the file as “TSV”, ie tab-separated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/udcFTuG7",{"TSV","Data"}, NumberPoint -> ","]
ListPlot[Transpose@data[[3;;]]]
```

[image]